# How to properly override a dispatchKeyEvent in Android

Tags: android, keyevent

I get

```
D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier( 2144): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.`
D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier( 2144): in com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41689658
```

warnings all over when I try to do this in my activity:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if ((/*some boolean checks*/) && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
            /*some custom functions*/
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

What is the correct way of overriding `dispatchKeyEvent` in the activity level? Are these warnings fine? Should I do corresponding changes in the `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` of my views?

Comment: What do you want to do with `dispatchKeyEvent()` method?

Comment: I want to override it **properly**. With the current snippet, `InputEventConsistencyVerifier` warnings are logged all over logcat. I want to know if these are expected and can be ignored.

Comment: Returning true without calling `super.dispatchKeyEvent()` is the source of this error.

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){

         enter();

            return true;
    }}
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
};
```

Comment: see http://androidprogramsamples.blogspot.in/2012/03/dispatchkeyeventgetkeycodegetactiongetr.html

Comment: I want to override the activity's dispatchKeyEvent. The link applies to views.

Answer (score 1):

As ForeverLearning pointed out in the comment is that `super.dispatchKeyEvent()` is not being called on your handled `DOWN` events, which is why on the up events it appears to the system to be an up event (your `return super.dispatchKeyEvent`) before having a down (your `return true`).

What Pratik Butani might have wanted to say in his code answer is that you could use the `KeyEvent.Action_UP` instead of the `DOWN` to get rid of the specific error.

The problem with just calling it as well is that it will be propagaded further down as well (handled by other routines as well / double).

**TL;DR:** If you want to keep functionality as is, and get rid of the error, consider also **NOT** calling `dispatchKeyEvent` on `ACTION_UP` of the action/situation/i.e. enter press. E.g.

```
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

    // No matter if up or down, we handle this event =>
    // => return true (which gets rid of the OPs error)

    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        /*some custom functions*/
    }

    return true;
}
return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
```